# Cycle diagram of a Symmetric group in LaTex

Tags: diagrams

I have these permutations

[image]

And I want to draw in LaTex something like this for the first one:
[image]
and this for the second one:[image]
How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why do'nt you simply use the standard notations $(1 2 3)$ for the first permutation and $(1 2 3) (4 5)$ for the second?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks!, I don't use that notation, because that's exactly what I want to explain using the circular diagram.

Comment: If you absolutely want to draw diagrams, you should try to do it with `tikz-cd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

[image]

This is done with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib`, so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef pentacycle(text t) =
    save n; numeric n; n = 0;
    save p; numeric p[];
    for $ = t:
        p[incr n] = $;
    endfor
    save w, z;
    image(
        for a = 1 upto n:
            pair z, w; 
            z = 20 up rotated ((1-a) / n * 360);
            w = 20 up rotated ((1-p[a]) / n * 360);
            label(decimal a, z);
            if abs (z-w) < eps:
                drawarrow subpath (1, -5) of fullcircle 
                    scaled 10 shifted z shifted 5 down;
            else:
                drawarrow z {w-z rotated 30} .. w
                    cutbefore fullcircle scaled 10 shifted z
                    cutafter  fullcircle scaled 10 shifted w;
            fi
        endfor
    )
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    interim ahangle := 30;
    draw pentacycle(2,3,1,4,5);
    draw pentacycle(2,3,1,5,4) shifted 60 right;
    draw pentacycle(2,3,4,5,1) shifted 120 right;
    draw pentacycle(3,4,5,1,2) shifted 180 right;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```